# Unexpected token "LIMIT" in DB2

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, db2, db2-luw

My Rails app is connected to a remote DB2 database, and when migrating I'm stumbling into this error:

```
==  DropLegacyProject: migrating ========================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

RuntimeError: Failed to execute statement due to: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "LIMIT" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "FETCH FIRST <n> ROWS ONLY".  SQLSTATE=42601 SQLCODE=-104: SELECT  projects.* FROM projects WHERE projects.id < 17 LIMIT 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **bhamby** suggested, DB2 does not support the `LIMIT x` keyword... *by default*.

But starting with DB2 v9.7.2, [support for `LIMIT x` can be enabled](http://freedb2.com/2010/07/14/top-3-ways-to-return-top-10-rows-by-an-sql-query/) via the [DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR registry variable](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html):

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
db2stop
db2start
```

...and it works!

Answer (score 5):

DB2 does not support the `LIMIT x` keyword.

As the error message says, the proper way to do this would to use `FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY` instead.